# Messages on a RabbitMQ Topic Exchange queue

Tags: rabbitmq

**Note: Using RabbitMQ .NET library**

I have a Topic Exchange on my RabbitMQ called *FXTO.HK* and a binding key of *FXTO.#*
The server publishes messages to this queue.

On the client side, the queues have a unique and random name but use the same binding key of *FXTO.#*

We use the Subscription class from the library on the client side which works fine: ie. the message is received by all clients at the same time.

However, in RabbitMQ management UI, the server queue (*FXTO.HK*) is showing to have all the messages in the queue (they are not removed from the queue).

Am I doing anything wrong in my setup? When will these messages be removed from the server queue?

Answer (score 0):

This question is better suited to the [RabbitMQ Discuss](https://lists.rabbitmq.com/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/rabbitmq-discuss) mailing list.

> However, in RabbitMQ management UI, the server queue (FXTO.HK) is showing to have all the messages in the queue (they are not removed from the queue).

This strongly suggests you're not ack'ing messages after consuming them.  Looking at [this](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/file/default/projects/examples/client/Subscriber/src/examples/Subscriber.cs) example, I see you need to call [Subscription.Ack](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v2.7.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-2.7.0-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns.Subscription.html#method-M%3aRabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns.Subscription.Ack) after each call to `Subscription.Next` (or start the `Subscription` in [NoAck mode](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v2.7.0/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-2.7.0-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns.Subscription.html#method-M%3aRabbitMQ.Client.MessagePatterns.Subscription.#ctor%28RabbitMQ.Client.IModel,System.String,System.Boolean%29))

Comment: I do Ack the messages. The UI shows message numbers as Ready = x, Unacked = 0, and Total = x. So it seems the acknowledgement works

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what "client" and "server" mean in your question. RabbitMQ doesn't understand clients and servers other than considering itself a server for everyone. Neither publishers nor consumers are inherently clients or servers.

You say "I have a Topic Exchange on my RabbitMQ called FXTO.HK and a binding key of FXTO.# The server publishes messages to this queue.", but that doesn't make sense. Are messages being published to the `FXTO.HK` *exchange* or some other *queue*? I think that confusion may be at the root of your issue:

- If your messages with `FXTO.??` routing keys are being published to an *exchange* (i.e. you have "exchange" set in the parameters to the `publish` function) with *one or more queues bound to it* with the binding key of `FXTO.#`, those messages will be duplicated into each bound queue. Those messages will remain in each queue until they are consumed in no-ack mode or acknowledged. If you happen to have a queue with the same name as the exchange bound to the exchange (e.g exchange `FXTO.HK` is bound to queue `FXTO.HK` with some binding key), no special behavior will occur as a result of their sharing the same name. Messages will be duplicated into each matching bound queue including `FXTO.HK`, and will sit in that queue until a consumer connects to it and acknowledges them.
- If your messages are being published to a *queue* (i.e. you don't have "exchange" set in the parameters to `publish` or you're using the default exchange) called `FXTO.HK`, your messages will remain in that queue until a consumer connects to that queue and receives them/acknowledges them. No exchange/fanout routing will occur.